# PHP Mysqli count returning 0

Tags: php

I have a field in the database called date where the content is: 29/07/2014

Now, I'm trying to return how many fields have today's date and I actually know that there's 1.

This is my query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `date` = date('d/m/Y') ");

$totalToday=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Why is $totalToday return 0 when it should be returning 1 ? Syntax ?

Comment: Are you able to fetch any record by your query itself?

Comment: @RonakPatel `$result` is not an array, it's a `mysqli_result` object.

Comment: You can't put function calls in strings like that. The query executed is probably trying to match against any dates that are literally "date('d/m/y')"

Comment: `date('d/m/Y')`  << that is a PHP date function. It is recommended to change your table so that the `date` column is a real MySQL DATE type, rather than a string. However, you can get the date formatted that way in MySQL with `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: In the spirit of `OOP`, use `$result->num_rows`. Not that it solves the problem, though.

Comment: You have inadvertently called the [MySQL DATE() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) in a way that is syntactically valid, but doesn't make any sense to the RDBMS.

Comment: May I suggest error checking? I can't understand why so many people prefer to code by guessing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies in your query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `date` = date('d/m/Y') ");
```

Your query string literally means "Take every column from `mytable` where the `date` field is equal to the evaluation of the **MySQL `date` function** with the input `'d/m/Y'`."

In order to get the **`date` function from PHP** evaluated into your query string, you need to evaluate it separately:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `date` = '" . date('d/m/Y') . "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL function for formatting dates is [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). The first argument is the time to format, the second argument is a format string, and the formatted elements are prefixed with `@`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `date` = date_format(NOW(), '@d/@m/@Y') ");
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why doesn't it? Since he was using the wrong function, his query wasn't matching anything, so he got 0 rows. Using the correct function fixes that.

Comment: Okay, your edit means it will work now.  The original version didn't answer the question.

Comment: Why didn't you say that the problem was that I left out an argument? I had the right approach, I just made a small mistake.

Comment: Because I wasn't aware of the correct syntax myself until I saw your fix. :)  I just thought you'd given one invalid query to replace another one